# android adwhirl integration problem

Tags: android

i have implemented adwhirl to show adds in my app. and it is working fine in portait mode. when i change the oreintation to landscape mode the add is displaying but width is not fill parent(not showing on the whole screen). it is showing in the middle.

i didn't found any solution for the same..pls help me in this case..

Answer (score 0):

Some ad networks (AdMob for example) serve only fixed-size ads. They can not be stretched in order to fill parent.